# How to make item toggle slide using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using

`$('#analytics').toggle("slide");`

to toggle slide item but how can i make it slide out from the right-hand side ?

Comment: have you try jquery ui  ?

Comment: AFAIK, `toggle()` Toggle between `hide()` and `show()`